# Refresh after adding DIV dynamically using jQuery Mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I'm trying to add a **div** dynamically using jQuery mobile, but after adding it, the CSS is not applied even with the **refresh**.

The is the [example](http://jsfiddle.net/Mils/YszNQ/).

Code :

```
$(function() {
     $("#data").append('<div data-role="collapsible"><h3>Div2</h3><p>Content Div2...</p></div>');
     $("#data").listview("refresh");
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`collapsibleset()`](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.3.0-rc.1/docs/content/content-collapsible-set-methods.html) instead of `listview("refresh")`:

```
$("#data").collapsibleset();
```

See [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/YszNQ/2/).

Comment: Ah, I see. Try just `collapsibleset()`. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I"m use such method

```
try{
    $("#data").listview("refresh");
}catch{
    $("#data").listview();
}finally{
    $('[data-role=collapsible]').collapsible();
}
```

This problem occurs when an item is added to the dynamic